# How to provide my own 'clean_is_staff' on UserChangeForm?

Tags: django, validation

I'm working on a django project that I inherited, and I want to add validation when setting the 'is_staff' attribute of a user.  I can't figure out how ...

My goal is to ensure that a regular user (a student, in this case) cannot be given 'is_staff' privilege by mistake.  This is extra protection beyond training the existing administrators not to do this Bad Thing.

The project uses the standard auth.user, and has its own Profile class.  That all works fine.  Once a student registers, he or she has a User object and a Profile object. Staff users are/should be created only by an administrator, using the standard 'Add New User' action in the Admin UI.

BTW, this is Django 1.8.

My idea is to add a custom 'clean_is_staff()' method and raise ValidationError if the User being edited has a Profile object when the administrator tries to save changes with 'is_staff' set to True.

So I did two things:  wrote 'ValidatingUserChangeForm' as a subclass of UserChangeForm, to put my logic in, and wrote 'ValidatingUserAdmin', to have a code path to ValidatingUserChangeForm.

It's not working; my ValidatingUserAdmin seems to work fine, but my ValidatingUserChangeForm is ignored.  I'm sure it's my fault - guidance welcome.

I'll provide the output in a comment to this post.

```
from change.forms import ValidatingUserChangeForm


class ValidatingUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

def __init__(self, name='admin', app_name='admin'):
    super(ValidatingUserAdmin, self).__init__(self, name='admin', app_name='admin')

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ValidatingUserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    ###logger.debug("ValidatingUserAdmin::get_form(): about to return '{0}'".format(form))
    return form


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ValidatingUserAdmin)
```

And forms.py:

```
class ValidatingUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
""" 
The goal of overriding Django's UserChangeForm is 
to keep the Application Stats report correct.

I hope this is the way to provide custom 'clean_is_staff()' service.
The rule I want to enforce is that a registered user cannot be
given 'is_staff' permissions.  
""" 

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(ValidatingUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def clean_is_staff(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data["is_staff"] 
    # do code here to check for a Profile object for this user.
    return value

def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super(ValidatingUserChangeForm, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your model admin class to use your custom form:

```
class ValidatingUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ValidatingUserChangeForm
    ...

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ValidatingUserAdmin)
```

You can remove `get_form` from the model admin class (setting `form` is enough) and from the form class (forms don't need a `get_form` method).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `'self'` parameter in `clean_is_staff` method

```
def clean_is_staff(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data["is_staff"] 
    # do code here to check for a Profile object for this user.
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like you want to add you own new field 'clean_is_staff' in User model. then inherit the AbstractUser and override the current User model.

**views.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):

        email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        mobile = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, unique=True)
        clean_is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        ...
```

**admin.py**

```
class AccountUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
        ('Info', {'fields': ('mobile', 'email', 'clean_is_staff',)}),
    )

admin.site.register(User, AccountUserAdmin)
```

Comment: This might work as your example is written, but it is not what I want.

The UserChangeForm already exists, in contrib.auth.forms.UserChangeForm.  And 'is_staff' is an existing Field in that Form.

I just want to alter/extend the validation that it does on the existing is_staff field.